# Android - gps tracking service by google location client

Tags: android, gps, location-client

I use locationclient to get location in my app (use this lesson of google https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) with Timer to track location. It ok but my app have some activity, when i finish activity main, tracking stop. I want to track location during app running. Any solution to use google location client in service?